# Power Query - Value.Divide(Value.Add( )) returns all "null" results

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, microsoft-powerbi

When I create a calculated field in Microsoft Power Query feature ("***Get and Transform***" since Excel 2016) I use a combination two simple formulae: ***Value.Divide()*** and ***Value.Add()***. For some reason, this does not work and all I get is null values.

Here is the series of steps that I do:

1. Get&Transform data from .csv;
2. Arrange fields (columns), rename;
3. Add
   some custom ones;

**The one giving me problems is as follows:**

---

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Add Cost per result", "ROAS", each Value.Divide(Value.Add([Website conversion value], [#"Mobile app purchases conversion value (corr.)"]), [#"Amount spent (GBP)"]))
```

Or, as copied from a "graphical interface":

```
= Value.Divide(Value.Add([Website conversion value], [#"Mobile app purchases conversion value (corr.)"]), [#"Amount spent (GBP)"])
```

---

- ***[Website conversion value]*** is imported from the original .csv;
- ***[#"Mobile app purchases conversion value (corr.)"]*** is calculated field ("Add column...");
- ***[#"Amount spent (GBP)"]*** is imported from the original .csv, I suspect that this might be the problem one - why does it have a # prepended when it was there originally during the import? Isn't this a symbol for a "table"?;

Many thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It seems that the "***Value. ...()***" formulae in Power Query do not work with *null* values. So, I replaced the null records with a 0, which might not be the most correct approach but it worked.

Problem solved :)